# Not postback button in asp

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i have found lots of example to create a button without postback. However, all fail in my case, so can you check it?

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnNew" CssClass="btnNew btn" runat="server" Text="New" OnClientClick="showDiv(); return false;" />
    <button id="btnNew" class="btnNew " onclick="showDiv();">New</button>
    //jQuery function => $("#btn").Click();
```

For this button, i won't use it in server, so it should be a pure html button..

Can anyone tell me what's wrong of above code?

Comment: If you debug your code do you see any errors in your console?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to call `server` side function simply add `input type='button'`

```
<button type="button" id="btnNew" class="btnNew" onclick="showDiv();">New</button>
```

OR

```
<input type="button" id="btnNew" class="btnNew " value="New" onclick="showDiv();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Letting the function "showDiv" return "false" should do the trick.

```
function showDiv() {
   [your code]
   return false;
}
```